# Conditionally highlighting checkbox label, after fetching state from storage

Tags: jquery, checkbox, local-storage

My code assigns the checked state of checkboxes to local-storage, then retrieves them on 'page load' using this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/).

The tutorial example works, but I want to go a step further, and perform the additional task of conditionally setting the background color of the checkbox's label, based on whether the checkbox state is checked or not.

I've tried adding the following to replace the last line of jQuery, but it just highlights all of the checkboxes.

```
$("#" + key).prop('checked', value).parent('label').css('background', 'yellow');
```

Here's it is in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/525a2ofn/). So in that example, if it were working as I described, if I click Norway, Norway would be highlighted in yellow.

Any suggestions?

```
<div id="checkbox-container">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="UN246" value="Finland" />Finland</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="UN579" value="Norway" />Norway</label>
</div>

var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
$checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line to this:

```
$("#" + key).prop('checked', value).parent('label').css('background', value?'yellow':'');
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/525a2ofn/5/** (code snippet doesn't allow *localStorage*)

This uses a [*ternary operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

- If `value` is `TRUE` , the `background` is set to `'yellow'`.
- If `value` is `FALSE`,the `background` is set to `''` *(empty)*, effectively setting it to default.

Comment: that works beautifully.  Your explanations are very clear too.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using each function with a json object contain key => id and value => value of check box(true | false). So you must check if value == true then 
set css style for that checkbox.

My correction here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/525a2ofn/4/):

```js
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
  $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
  $checkboxes.each(function() {
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
  if(value){
   $("#" + key).parent('label').css('background', 'yellow');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox-container">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN40" value="Austria" />Austria</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN246" value="Finland" />Finland</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="UN579" value="Norway" />Norway</label>
</div>
```

Comment: A very clean solution, and more understandable for me than the solution from @myfunkyside, although his came first so I'll tick that one as the accepted answer.